# sending sms/email to user and performing actions in salesforce based on email response

Tags: email, sms, sendsmsactivity

For an upcoming project module, there is a requirement to send SMS and Email to user. Later based on the Email response, further process to be carried out. I am aware about sending email thing but would like to learn about sending SMS and processing email response. Can you guys suggest any trailheads/knowledge articles where I can find related information.Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Have you tried searching trailhead or `<insert search engine of choice here>` for the features you want to learn about? Part of the expectation on this site is that you have done some research before asking a question, so a question asking people to do all of your research for you probably isn't a very good fit. Beyond that, searching on your own is likely to get you results faster than asking a stranger on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any Salesforce OOTB capability to send SMS . You might need to use any of the third party tools (plenty of tools available in AppExchange) .

Regarding processing email response, Set up an email service to handle incoming email, and configure the service to process messages according to your business needs.